# Pregunta sobre "import" / "from import"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

No entiendo porque, con algunos módulos de terceros que utilizo, al intentar:

```
import foo
```

no me deja acceder a `foo.bar`;

sin embargo, al utilizar `from foo import bar`

sí puedo acceder correctamente a `bar`

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que `bar` se trata de un módulo o paquete `foo`, no hay diferencia, no importa. Las dos declaraciones tienen exactamente el mismo resultado:

```
import foo.bar.bazaar as baz
from foo.bar import bazaar as baz
```

El `import ... as` requiere que el módulo `foo.bar` se inyecte en el espacio de nombres `foo` como el atributo `bar`, además de estar en `sys.modules`, mientras que el `from ... import ... as` busca `foo.bar` en `sys.modules`.

(Tenga en cuenta también que `import foo.bar` solo asegura que el módulo `foo.bar` esté dentro `sys.modules` y sea accesible `foo.bar`, pero que aún no se haya inicializado del todo)

Otro Ejemplo:

```
>>> import os.path as path
>>> path
<module 'posixpath' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
>>> from os import path
>>> path
<module 'posixpath' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
```

Si `bar` no es un módulo o paquete, el segundo formulario no funcionará; en su lugar, se lanza un traceback:

```
>>> import os.walk as walk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named walk
```

> Fuente SO: [from … import OR import … as for modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245722/8933039)

---

La diferencia entre `import module` y `from module import foo` es principalmente subjetiva. Elija el que más le guste y sea consistente en su uso de él. Aquí hay algunos puntos para ayudarlo a decidir.

`import module`

- **Pros:**

  - Menos mantenimiento de sus declaraciones `import`. No es necesario agregar ninguna importación adicional para comenzar a usar otro elemento del módulo
- **Contras:**

  - Escribir su código `module.foo` puede ser tedioso y redundante (el tedio se puede minimizar usando `import module as mo` y luego escribiendo `mo.foo`)

`from module import foo`

- **Pros:**

  - Menos tipeo para usar `foo`
  - Más control sobre qué elementos de un módulo se puede acceder.
- **Contras:**

  - Para usar un nuevo elemento del módulo, debe actualizar su declaración `import`.
  - Pierdes el contexto sobre `foo`. Por ejemplo, está menos claro `ceil()` qué hace en comparación `conmath.ceil()`.

Cualquiera de los métodos es aceptable, pero **no lo uses** `from module import`.

Para cualquier gran conjunto razonable de código, si es probable que `import *`  lo esté consolidando en el módulo, no se puede eliminar. Esto se debe a que es difícil determinar qué elementos utilizados en el código provienen de 'módulo', lo que hace que sea fácil llegar al punto en el que crees que ya no usas ningún `import`, pero es extremadamente difícil estar seguro.

> - Fuente SO: [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/710603/8933039)